# How to get specific cell position using value of cell in Aslxs gem in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, axlsx

I want to get the position or index of a specific cell in worksheet using the value of the cell.
I have a hash and i want to check at what position in the first row the key of the hash is present and then place the value in the current row in the column where the header contains the key.

Comment: Please provide an example of some kind so we can help.

Comment: Axlsx (or caxlsx) is a gem for generating a spreadsheet, not reading one. As such, you should already know what you put in as the columns. I would structure your program so you remember what you created for headers. You could create a simple hash to map column names to numbers.There are several other gems for reading/modifying spreadsheets, if that is what you are interested in.